# Can't add active class to Bootstrap dropdown menu with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

### Overview

I have a navbar with `li` elements. I add the class `active` to the element that corresponds to a variable `$page`.

For each of the list elements, I place code similar to this:

```
<li<?= $page=="new" ? " class='active'" : null ?>><a href="<?= $rootUrl ?>?page=new">New event</a></li>
```

That way, using this example, if the `$page` is `"new"`, I add the `active` class to the `li` element.

This works with top-level list items as well as dropdown children.

### Issue

I want the parent element of the dropdown children to also show the `active` class when one of its children is active.

To do this with a dropdown with page values `"new"`, `"existing"` and `"gateway"`, I use:

```
<li class="dropdown<?= $page=="new"||$page=="existing"||$page="gateway" ? " active" : null ?>">
```

However, this doesn't work; when inspecting the element in the Chrome developer tools, the only class is `dropdown1` and any other added classes have disappeared.

Adding the `active` class manually in Chrome developer tools produces the correct result.

### Full code

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li<?= $page=="dashboard" ? " class='active'" : null ?>><a href="<?= $rootUrl ?>?page=dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown<?= $page=="new"||$page=="existing"||$page="gateway" ? " active" : null ?>">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Events <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li<?= $page=="new" ? " class='active'" : null ?>><a href="<?= $rootUrl ?>?page=new">New event</a></li>
                <li<?= $page=="existing" ? " class='active'" : null ?>><a href="<?= $rootUrl ?>?page=existing">Existing events</a></li>
                <li<?= $page=="gateway" ? " class='active'" : null ?>><a href="<?= $rootUrl ?>?page=gateway">Gateway</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="<?= $rootUrl ?>?logout=true">Sign out</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### Question

How can I make the parent element of the dropdown have `active` class when one of its child elements has the `active` class?

Comment: tried var_dump($page) to see what value it has ?

Comment: @IseNgaRt Yes, it has the correct values. I can see this because the correct child element has the `active` class

Comment: $page="gateway" ? u miss a "=" here btw

Comment: @IseNgaRt And you've found the solution. Thank you. Post it as an answer and I'll accept!

Comment: Dont use <?= its very bad practice because it is not a php default. Also use a function to detect the active state something like <?php active( 'pagename' , $var ); ?> you can put in the echo into the function. As @IseNgaRt stated you just made a human mistake by missing a equal sign and to avoid these kind of mistakes use functions. To do repetitiv tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `"="` at `$page="gateway"` should be `$page=="gateway"`

```
<li class="dropdown<?= $page=="new"||$page=="existing"||$page="gateway" ? " active" : null ?>">
```